# Exiting on first error in recursive make

Tags: makefile, compilation

Submakes are being brought in by an include statement rather than a for loop like other SO answers for how to do this

```
  root makefile
  1 all: build
  2
  3 GIT_ROOT ?= $(shell git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
  4
  8
  9 # These get piggybacked onto by the sub-Makefiles
 10 BUILD_DEPS =
 11 CLEAN_DEPS =
 12 PACKAGE_DEPS =
 13 TEST_DEPS =
 14
 15 define validate_in_path
 16 @which $(1) >/dev/null || (echo "Expected to find '$(1)' in PATH" && exit 1)
 17 endef
 18
 19 include $(GIT_ROOT)/*/Makefile.sub
 20
 21 .PHONY: all build clean package
 22
 23 build: $(BUILD_DEPS)
```

Most of the submakes look something like this where all they do is call a function upstream and pass in parameters for what path that function uses.

What exactly am I supposed to do here to have the entire make process end, meaning all other recursively started makes as well, if line 5 in one this sub-make were to fail.

What I really don't want to do is put in shell logic here to do a PID kill the top level process if something exits with a non-zero code.

```
  sub makefile
  1 $(eval $(call declare_node_service,autoscaler))
  2 .PHONY += autoscaler clean-autoscaler package-autoscaler
  3
  4 autoscaler: node-lib
  5         $(call build_node,autoscaler)
  6
  7 clean-autoscaler:
  8         $(call clean_node,autoscaler)
  9
 10 package-autoscaler: autoscaler
 11         $(call package_node,autoscaler)
 12
 13 test-autoscaler: autoscaler
 14         $(call test_node,autoscaler)
```

Comment: Line 5? Do you mean one of the rules defined in one of the included makefiles? What do you want Make to do if one of those rules fails?

Comment: If line 5      $(call build_node,autoscaler) fails I want the top level make process to terminate as well as immediately end all other parallel running, recursively started make processes. Edited question for phrasing

Comment: There is no way to do that other than sending a SIGINT to the root make process (which will propagate to all children).